# How to assign programatically an InfoPath XSN to a Content Type

Tags: infopath, content-type

I had some content types and some XSN infopath files... I can link it by web interface and this works well but I must do this connection during feature activated event...

So... Is there any code to assign some XSN to a CT?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I now of is by manipulate the XmlDocuments property. The tag to insert looks like this:

```
<XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/customXsn"><ntns:customXsn xmlns:ntns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/of
fice/2006/metadata/customXsn"><ntns:xsnLocation>https://yourSite.com/sites/collection1/_cts/Kravspecifikation/c3136540975a4140customXsn.xsn</ntns:xsnLocation><ntns:cached>False</ntns:cached><ntns:openBy
Default>False</ntns:openByDefault><ntns:xsnScope>https://yourSite.com/sites/collection1</ntns:xsnScope></ntns:customXsn></XmlDocument>
```

See more here:

http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/08/copy-content-types/

and here:

http://www.sharepoint.bg/radi/post/Forcing-the-DIP-to-load-when-a-Word-Document-loads-from-SharePoint.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can publish your Infopath form to your site using SharePoint WSP , it will create a contentType for you.For details , you can have look at here.http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/deploy-infopath-form-as-sharepoint-feature-in-sharepoint2010/